# Why does this pointer point to "Horse cult" instead of "Horse horse"?

Tags: pointers, scope, pass-by-value

```
1   public class Horse {
2      Horse same;
3      String jimmy;
4   
5      public Horse(String lee) {
6         jimmy = lee;
7      }
8   
9      public Horse same(Horse horse) {
10        if (same != null) {
11           Horse same = horse;
12           same.same = horse;
13           same = horse.same;
14        }
15        return same.same;
16     }
17  
18     public static void main(String[] args) {
19        Horse horse = new Horse("youve been");
20        Horse cult = new Horse("horsed");
21        cult.same = cult;
22        cult = cult.same(horse);
23        System.out.println(cult.jimmy);
24        System.out.println(horse.jimmy);
25     }
26  }
```

When Java interpreter runs line 22, why did cult.same(horse) return a pointer that points to "Horse cult" instead of returning the pointer that points to "Horse horse" that same.same (where same was initialized in line 11) points to?

Comment: You have a field and a method in your `Horse` class both of which are called `same`.  I'm surprised your code even compiles, but in any case don't do that.

Comment: It's not actual code, it's from a discussion section in a data structure class

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable `same` is declared within `if` statement, it is not accessible outside the `if` block. Therefore in the `return` statement, it would find the `same` variable cult self.

Comment: I see! In python, scope was only involved when dealing with functions, I didn't realize if statement and while statement also has their own scopes in Java. Thank you so much for the help!